# How to check if click actually did anything, or alternative solution

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am creating some tests in Selenium using NUnit. I have an issue with some of my clicks not going through because the buttons haven't loaded properly.
I do have a wait that should wait until the buttons are clickable, but they seem to be clickable before they actually are, and the click fails.
I can see that the element does have the correct href link before i click, but nothing happens.

A static delay before clicking does "fix" it, but its a bad solution which slows the whole testing process and often breaks during stressful tests.

I am pretty sure it is the javascript on the page being slow and not having initialized properly before the click.

I was thinking of instead of checking if it is clickable, check if the click did anything instead.
I thought of matching the page source before and after the click, but not all clicks necessarily change the html, so that just broke other tests instead.

Here is my current click method. The wait seems to be pretty useless though.

```
    public void click(IWebElement element)
    {
        IsDisplayed(element);

        Console.Write("Clicking " + element.GetAttribute("href"));

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));

        element.Click();

        Console.WriteLine(" ✓");
    }
```

The test that fails regularly is one where i just open the page and click a button after checking some elements are displayed.

Comment: Please add code snippet into your question to get clear picture of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. As you have induced *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()`, once the element is returned you need to invoke  `click()` on it. Effectively you code block will be:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element)).Click();
```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can use `ExecuteScript()` from *IJavaScriptExecutor* as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element)));
```

Comment: Your example does seem more effecient, but in function how does it differ from waiting and then clicking the element as i did?

Comment: I think in your code block when you used `element.Click();` the _element_ which was returned from `IsDisplayed()` was considered but not the _element_ which was returned after `WebDriverWait()`. Hence I want you to invoke `click()` just after the _element_ is returned after `WebDriverWait()`

Comment: @Jaco9307 Update the question with the complete error stacktrace which you see

Comment: The issue is i dont get an error. It just clicks a button that doesn't work yet. The test just continues as if it worked, and then fails later when it can't find an expected element, because it didnt open the menu..

Comment: @Jaco9307 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I just get "JavaScriptError: Document was unloaded" in pretty much all my tests